# where can I find detailed resource on object state prediction for using with dead reckoning?

Tags: quaternions

I have a server and a client.
I have 40 opengl cubes. There state is described by 3d vector for position and 3x3 rotation matrix(or a quaternion).

How can I send intermediate packets and predict the object state on the client between those packets(extrapolation)?

for object position I can use a linear predictor on velocity.
How to predict quaternion states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing, parallel to what you're doing with linear velocity, is to use a linear predictor on angular velocity.

If you have two quaternions, **q_0** and **q_t**, representing global orientations that are **t** seconds apart, you can compute the finite difference between the two quaternions and use that to find an angular velocity that can be used for extrapolation.

1. Make sure that the inner-product between **q_0** and **q_t** is non-negative.  If it's negative, negate all the components of one of the quaternions.  This makes sure that we're not trying to go the long way around.  If your bodies are rotating really fast relative to your sampling, this is a problem and you'll need a more complicated model that accounts for the previous angular velocity and makes assumptions about maximum possible acceleration.  We'll assume that's not the case.
2. Then we compute the relative difference quaternion. **dq** = **q_t** * **q_0'** (where **q_0'** is the quaternion rotational inverse/conjugate).  If you have the luxury of having fixed-sized steps, you can stop here and predict then next orientation **t** seconds into the future: **q_2t = dq*d_t**.
3. If we can' step forward by integer multiples of **t**, we compute the angle of rotation from **dq**.  Quaternions and angular velocities are both variations on "axis-angle" representations of changes in orientation.  If you rotate by **Θ** around unit-length axis **[x,y,z]**, then the quaternion representation of that is **q** = **[cos(Θ/2), sin(Θ/2)x, sin(Θ/2)y, sin(Θ/2)z]** (using the quaternion convention where the *w* component comes first).  If you rotate by **Θ/t** around axis **[x,y,z]**, then the angular velocity is **v** = **[Θx,Θy,Θz]/t**.  So **v** = **Θ[q.x,q.y,q.z]/(t||[q.x,q.y,q.z]||)**.  We can compute the angle two ways: **Θ** = **2acos(q.w)** = **2asin(||[q.x,q.y,q.z]||)**.  These will always be the same because of step 1.  Numerics make it nicer to use *sine* since we need to find **m** = **||[q.x,q.y,q.z]||** anyway for the next step.
4. If **m** is large enough, then we just find the angular velocity:

   **v** = **2asin(m)[dq.x,dq.y,dq.z]/(m*t)**

   However, if **m**'s not large enough, we'll face numeric issues trying to divide by near-zero.  So programmers will use the Taylor expansion of the sinc() function around zero, which happens to be very accurate in this case.  Remember that **m** = **sin(Θ/2)**.  With **m<1e-4**, we can accurately compute **asin(m)/m = 6/(6-m*m)**.  Then you just need to multiply the result by **2*[dq.x,dq.y,dq.z]/t** and you have your angular velocity.  *Phew*.
5. Extrapolating is then a matter of multiplying your angular velocity times the time that has passed.  Then you go backwards, converting the angular change to a quaternion and multiplying it onto **q_t**.

It seems like there must be an easier way...

Comment: I know quaternions are different from traditional vectors, does the above conversion take care of the fact that the axis itself around which the object has an angle or orientation is subject to change?

Comment: @user494461 If I understand your question right, then yes, this takes care of that.  The quaternion **qd** is the quaternion that will rotate a body from **q_0** to **q_t**.  I.e., **qd** * **q_0** = **q_t**.  So the extrapolation assumes that global axis remains constant: **qd** * **qd** * **q_0** = **q_2t**.

Comment: no I mean the axis of the quaternion q_t might not be same as q_0..so just changing the quarternion by using angular velocity will never get the desired change

Comment: @user494461 From any orientation to any other orientation, there exists some transformation that will produce the change.  **qd** is the quaternion that represents the change in orientation that will move **q_0** to **q_t**.  If you convert it to angular velocity, it still represents the same change and unless some change is applied to the system (external torque or internal changes to the inertia tensor) then that angular velocity should remain constant.

Comment: shouldnt dq = q_t * q_0'  be dq = q_0'*q_t instead, since q0*dq=q_t ? also isnt the product non commutative.

Comment: @user494461 You're correct that quaternion products are non-commutative.  As to which equation order is correct, it depends on your convention.  I was assuming that the quaternions/matrices are transforming column vectors on the right; so the transformation goes on the left.  Using the column vector convention, I'm pretty sure the order I put things in is correct for finding the angular velocity of the body within the global frame of reference.

Comment: thanks..can you point me to a resource on "quaternions/matrices are transforming column vectors on the right" and "transformation goes on the left"...I have no idea on about what it is

Comment: @user494461 Rotation matrices (or the quaternion equivalent) transform vectors (points in space).  As mentioned before, the order in which the matrices are applied (i.e., multiplied) matters a lot.  The transformations that are closest to the vector are applied first.  Your vectors need to either be columns or rows.  If they're columns, they need to be on the right side of the matrices and if they're rows, they need to be on the left.  Otherwise, matrix multiplication is impossible.  Switching from one convention to the other is simply a matter of transposing and reversing multiplication order